# Значение, которое вносит слово "это"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

"Где я?" и "где это я?"; "что ты делаешь?" и "что это ты делаешь?"; "что с ним?" и "что это с ним?"

Какой смысл вносит слово "это" в этих и подобных примерах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Из словаря.** ЭТО. частица. 1. Усиливает вопросительное местоимение или наречие, а также другие отдельные слова в предложении. Кто это пришёл? Куда это ты идёшь? Ведь это я тебе звонил.

Частица ЭТО указывает на отдельные слова, выделяет и усиливает их, а также  может придавать им дополнительное значение.

Сравним:

(1) Что ты делаешь (чем занимаешься)?

(2) Что **это** ты делаешь (**непонятно**, что и зачем  ты делаешь; иногда с **негативной оценкой** **понятного** действия).

Answer (score 2):

Слово "это", по-моему, может придавать этим вопросам смысловой оттенок сильного удивления, недоумения, иронии (важна интонация, с которой произносятся вопросы).

Answer (score 1):

Наличие частицы «это» указывает на место и время: здесь и сейчас.